# How can I automatically add music from a playlist into a folder?

Tags: iphone, itunes, playlist, smart-playlist, spotify

I am switching from the default music player on my iPhone to using Spotify to play music. The recent updates have meant that I can't use the music player in the same as I used to and I much prefer Spotify in general.I still want to use iTunes on my Mac to organise playlists.

What I need to set up is essentially a reverse smart playlist. I have 2000 songs in my iTunes library but I only want 500 of those on my phone. Is there a way to have the songs that get put into my smart playlist (that gets synced to my phone) getting automatically copied into a folder in Finder and have that as the 'Local File Source' in Spotify? Or would I just have to do this manually?

Hopefully that makes sense, and any kind of help would be awesome!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AppleScript to copy the music to a specific folder. iTunes and the Finder both support AppleScript.

Use the included **Script Editor.app** in OS X to create your script. A starting point for your script is below:

```
tell application "iTunes"

    -- Get the recent purchases smart playlist
    set myPlaylistFiles to file tracks of playlist "Recent Purchases"

    -- With every local song/track
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in myPlaylistFiles

        set localTrack to item i of myPlaylistFiles

        set myPathToTrack to location of localTrack

        -- Add copy to folder code here…        

    end repeat

end tell
```

Feel free to [ask more questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about finishing this AppleScript.